How to get Postman Api call Transfer Time in postman script test
I have below postman script to validate API response time.
pm.test("Response time is greater than 1000ms", function () {
pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(1000);});

But my test is validating the total time taken for like DNS lookup, Handshake,Transfer Start etc.

Is there any way to validate postman api call Transfer Start time only as a part of postmam scripts test?

Postman doesn't provide a direct way to measure Transfer Start time separately.
But, you can calculate it by subtracting the start time from the current time when the response is received and then validating whether the Transfer Start time is less than 1000ms.
